# Check if url equals or is a sub-directory of?

Tags: java, regex, spring

I am looking for a best-practice way of doing the following in java (perhaps using apache commons, some spring utility, or maybe just plain java/regex):

I need to check if a given URL pattern equals a given string or is a sub-directory of the string:

```
String pattern = "/myPath";

if(StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(url, pattern) { // }
```

The above (using the commons methods) works for urls such as: `"../../myPath"`, `"../../myPath/"`, `"../../myPath/1/2"`

The problem is that it also matches: `"../../myPathABC"`.  This is not desired behavior since it is not the same directory or a sub-directory.

Answer (score 2):

Try [`URI.relativize(URI)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#relativize%28java.net.URI%29).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex I'd go with a regex match all with the following regex:

```
/^(\.\.\/)*myPath(\/|\/.*|$)/
```

it returns true for:

```
myPath
../../myPath
../../myPath/
../myPath
myPath/
```

and will return false for any variant of:

```
myPathABC
```

or anything not `myPath`. There probably is a way to do it with a java command though, java has a library for everything, I unfortunately don't know it.

Oh, it will **not** work for `/myPath/` but I'm not sure if you want that (you didn't state it), if you want that to match as well, add a `\/?` before `myPath`.